# 2D array printing

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

So, I am creating a program that reads in a file called ["Bankfile.txt"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9cb4.png) and the the first number "3" is to indicate how many account we are working with. The numbers "123" "467" and "499" are the bank account numbers and the numbers next to each is their original balances. In my code I am using a 2D array to scan them in. I think I have everything correct in scanning them in but when I run the program the account numbers are being printed very weird as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9V2m.png). Any ideas on why it is being printed like this?

Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
FILE* file;
file = fopen("bankfile.txt","r");
int accounts,b=1,w=2,d=3,u=4,i,j,accNum,origBal;
float interest = .0185; 
float test;
float accountInfo[accNum][origBal];

fscanf(file, "%d", &accounts);

for(i = 0; i < accounts; i++)
      {
      fscanf(file, "%d", &accountInfo[i]);
      for(j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            {
            fscanf(file, "%f", &accountInfo[i][j]);
             printf("Account %d has a balance of $%.2f\n", accountInfo[i], accountInfo[i][j]);
            }

      } 

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: some general remarks: 1.) format your code! 2.) don't use `float`, floating-point literals in C are `double` for a reason. 3.) multiple declarations in a single line can be confusing, especially if *some* of them are initialized and others aren't -- more lines don't hurt 4.) don't use `system("pause");` -- not being portable is just *one* of the issues ...  and 5.) show your "bankfile.txt" to allow some diagnostics ...

Comment: regarding "5.)" --- I assume your problem is that there's whitespace in your input file and you never scan for that in your `fscanf()` calls.

Comment: The biggest mistake here is a conceptual one - the misusage of a 2D array: `accountInfo` is a matrix; `accountInfo[i]` is a 1D (simple) array; in C that is a pointer (if you may an int representing a mem address). After that there may come the others that are implementation related: `accountInfo` declaration, 2nd `for` loop,...

Comment: @CristiFati an array is *never* a pointer, it's just implicitly converted to one when appropriate (e.g. as a function argument). But indeed, there are problems related to arrays, the first is the dimensions of `accountInfo` are actually uninitialized variables.

Comment: Looking a bit closer at this code: it just doesn't make sense! enable all warnings available in your compiler and start understanding them ....

Comment: Yes, true sorry for my formulation, I was trying to "save some chars", an array is definitely not a pointer (but a list of elements) yet it is being referred by one (address of the 1st element).

Comment: You must give values to `accNum` and `origBal` before they can be used to define the size of an array

Answer (score 1):

Ok what you have here is **not** a *2-dimensional array* -- this is conceptually wrong. An account number only has *one* balance associated with it. So what you have is only a single dimension, but your data has several fields ... that's where you use a `struct` in C. Here's some example code that would produce the output you expect:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* data structure holding a bank account */
typedef struct account
{
    int id;
    double balance;
} account;

int main(void)
{
    int cap = 1024; /* initial capacity of account array */
    int count = 0;  /* number of accounts */
    char buf[1024]; /* buffer for a line of text */
    char *tok;      /* token from text line */
    FILE *bankfile;
    int i;

    account *accounts = malloc(cap * sizeof(account));

    bankfile = fopen("bankfile.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(buf, 1024, bankfile))
    {
        int accId;
        tok = strtok(buf, " \t\r\n");
        if (!tok) continue;

        accId = atoi(tok);
        if (accId > 0)
        {
            /* first token in line was a positive integer */

            tok = strtok(0, " \t\r\n");
            if (tok)
            {
                /* there was a second token in the same line, then we found
                 * an account with a balance */

                accounts[count].id = accId;
                accounts[count].balance = atof(tok);

                if (++count == cap)
                {
                    cap *= 2;
                    accounts = realloc(accounts, cap * sizeof(account));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(bankfile);

    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        printf("Account %d has a balance of $%.2f\n",
                accounts[i].id, accounts[i].balance);

    }

    free(accounts);
    return 0;
}
```

This can be simplified by first reading the first line and then only allocating as many elements of `account` as needed.

<sub>of course, for *production*, add error checking to `fopen()` and `malloc()` and friends ...</sub>

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you don't understand the concept of two-dimensional arrays. When you have a 2D array (`foo`) and add two arrays into that it will look something like this.

```
int foo[][] = { {1,2,3} {4,5,6} };
```

And when you call `foo[0]` it will actually refer to the first array you added (i.e `[1,2,3]`) and `foo[1]` will refer to the second array. You should instead use two seperate arrays called `accountNum` and `accountBal`.

Finally you never give values to `accNum` or `origBal` which makes your 2D array an empty array. So you could instead dynamically allocate memory for them based on the `accounts` variable.

Keeping this in mind you should change your main logic to solve these issues.

```
fscanf(file, "%d", &accounts);
accountNum = malloc(sizeof(int) * accounts);
accountBal = malloc(sizeof(float) * accounts);

for(i = 0; i < accounts; i++) {
  fscanf(file, "%d", &accountNum[i]);
  fscanf(file, "%f", &accountBal[i]);
  printf("Account %d has a balance of $%.2f\n", accountNum[i], accountBal[i]);
}

free(accountBal);
free(accountNum);
```